# NDesk.Options: how to register required parameters correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am trying to utilize the `OptionSet` class in the following way:

```
  string resultsFileName = null;
  bool isHelp = false;

  var p = new OptionSet() {
    { "r=|resultsFile=",  "The file with the results", v => { resultsFileName = v; } }
    { "h|help", "Show this help", v => { isHelp = (v != null); } },
  };

  try
  {
    p.Parse(args);
  }
  catch (OptionException e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid arguments: " + e.Message);
    ShowHelp(p);
    return;
  }
```

Thus, `resultsFile` option is expected to be *required* (according to documentation: http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionValueType.html). However, when I run the program as is (i.e. with no command line arguments) the exception is not thrown. Please assist.

**Update:** It looks in debugger like when no command line options are provided, the `private void AssertValid (int index)` method will be never reached to `throw new OptionException`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [How to enforce required command-line options with NDesk.Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427306/how-to-enforce-required-command-line-options-with-ndesk-options), and the [answer is the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427306/how-to-enforce-required-command-line-options-with-ndesk-options/3754829#3754829): NDesk.Options doesn't support that.

Quoting myself:

As per the [OptionValueType.Required](http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionValueType.html#F:NDesk.Options.OptionValueType.Required) docs, the `=` within an option specification doesn't apply to the OptionSet as a whole, but just to the *value* for that specific option.

The importance of this is really only relevant in two scenarios, so first let's consider the OptionSet parser:

```
string a = null;
string b = null;
var options = new OptionSet {
    { "a=", v => a = v },
    { "b=", v => b = v },
};
```

Scenario 1 where it's important is that OptionSet.Parse() works in a single-pass, forward-only manner, and does *not* look at option values to determine if they "should be" values.  Thus, consider:

```
options.Parse(new[]{"-a", "-b"});
```

The result of this will be that `a` has the value `"-b"`, and `b` is `null`. Since the handler for `-a` *requires* a value, it *always* gets the following value (unless the value is "encoded" into the original option, e.g. `-a=value`).

The second place where this is important is when a value-requiring option is the last option, and there isn't a value present for it:

```
options.Parse(new[]{"-a"});
```

This will throw an OptionException, as the handler for `-a` *requires* a value, and no value is present.

Consequently, if you have an option that itself is required (as opposed to an option that requires a value), you need to manually check for this:

```
string dir = null;
new OptionSet {
    { "o=", v => dir = v },
}.Parse (args);

if (dir == null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException ("Missing required option -o=DIR");
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer! (a little pitty that this functionality is not supported, though, since it would contribute to robustness of the command-line arguments validation).