# Mono.Options: Check if an invalid option is given

Tags: c#, mono

I've defined

```
var p = new OptionSet () {
 // various options defined
};
```

Then I

```
p.Parse(args)
```

If I call my program with

```
myprogram --thisOptionIsNotDefined
```

I would like to display a help message, and NOT continue. But Parse() doesn't throw an OptionException when it encounters an invalid option. What do I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427306/how-to-enforce-required-command-line-options-with-ndesk-options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can interrogate the return of `OptionSet.Parse()` to find any invalid parameters.

From the NDesk OptionSet [documentation](http://www.ndesk.org/doc/ndesk-options/NDesk.Options/OptionSet.html):

> OptionSet.Parse(IEnumerable), returns a List of all
>   arguments which were not matched by a registered NDesk.Options.Option.

Answer (score 1):

`OptionSet.Parse()` returns any unprocessed arguments. However, note that this may also includes any actual (non-option) argument of your program, e.g. input files. In that case you can't just check that nothing is returned.

E.g. parsing the below `args` will return `["input.txt", "--thisOptionIsNotDefined"]`.

```
myprogram input.txt --thisOptionIsNotDefined
```

To solve this particular problem, I wrote an extension method `p.ParseStrict(args)`. It simply checks that no options remain unprocessed after parsing (taking `--` into account).

```
public static class MonoOptionsExtensions
{
    public static List<string> ParseStrict(this OptionSet source, IEnumerable<string> arguments)
    {
        var args = arguments.ToArray();
        var beforeDoubleDash = args.TakeWhile(x => x != "--");

        var unprocessed = source.Parse(beforeDoubleDash);

        var firstUnprocessedOpt = unprocessed.Find(x => x.Length > 0 && (x[0] == '-' || x[0] == '/'));
        if (firstUnprocessedOpt != null)
            throw new OptionException("Unregistered option '" + firstUnprocessedOpt + "' encountered.", firstUnprocessedOpt);

        return unprocessed.Concat(args.SkipWhile(x => x != "--").Skip(1)).ToList();
    }
}
```